# IPv6 support for proxy.pac

Tags: linux, firefox, proxy, ipv6, proxy.pac

I have a Linux system with Firefox and for example this proxy.pac from the server:

```
if (shExpMatch(host, "*.de")) {
return "PROXY [fd00::1]:8080; " + "PROXY [fd00::2]:8080";
}
```

With IPv4 it works perfectly fine, but IPv6 not. What did I wrong?
What I want is to have a proxy.pac that works with IPv6 and do the same behavior as in this script.

Comment: You are misusing the ULA addressing. The ULA address block is `fc00::/7`, and it is divided into two parts: `fc00::/8` and `fd00::/8`. The `fc00::/8` part is reserved and cannot be used at this time. The `fd00::/8` block is available for local assignment, but it is subject to some rules, one of which is that the 40 bits following the `fd` must be randomly chosen, and it is obvious that you are not doing that.

Comment: Also, a proxy cannot source ULA addressing to the public Internet as the packets will be dropped by the ISP. ULA addressing is for packets that will never be used on the public Internet. Every IPv6 host should already have Global addressing, so you should use that for your proxy.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for your replay :)
I also tried a global address i.e. 200X. Even with that it dosnt work.

The only thing what I found online was, that IPv6 is not supported in a proxy.pac (Linux). 

Have you a example with IPv6 that would work like the example in my earlier post?